# SwiftUI State var access inside a function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is probably pretty simple but for some reason I can’t find an easy way to fix it so far.

I have this code:

```
struct Home: View {
   @State var leftRollEditing = false

   var body: some View {
      // ... some unrelated code...
      HStack {
         Button {
            updateRoll()
         } label: {
            Image("Dice1")
         }
      }
      HStack {
         VStack {
             Image("myImage")
                .padding()
                .blinkBorder(on: $leftRollEditing)
             Text("MyText")
         }
      }
      // ... some more unrelated code ...
      HStack {
          Button {
              self.leftRollEditing = true
          } label: {
              Text("Edit Left Roll")
          }
      }
   }

   func updateRoll() {
      if self.leftRollEditing {
          leftRollEditing = false
          //... some more stuff
      }
   }
}
```

So this code compiles but when I access leftRollEditing in the `updateRoll()` function if statement, it doesn’t get me what it was last updated to. leftRollEditing gets updated to `true` with the Button tap but when I access it’s value in the `updateRoll()` function, it’s not the correct value.

I also tried `_leftRollEditing` and `_leftRollEditing.wrappedValue`  but they’re also not correct.

What is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call `updateRoll`?

Comment: It’s called in a bunch of Buttons right above the "myImage" area. Let me update the code here. @Paulw11 updated.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me -- click the "Edit Left Roll" button and `leftRollEditing` is set to `true`. Click the `updateRoll` button and it's set to `false`. I put this at the top of the `View` to show the state: `Text("Roll editing: \(leftRollEditing ? "True" : "False")")`

Comment: So strange, for me it doesn't even go in the if statement inside the updateRoll() function because even though it is set to true earlier, when it comes to the if check, it looks as it is false.

Comment: There's probably some related code in the unrelated code sections.